# How can I improve this login?

Tags: php, security

I have this code:

```
if (strcmp($user->pass, crypt($password, $user->pass)) == 0) {
    echo 'good';
} else {
    echo 'kill';
}
```

in PHP and would like to know how this can be improved, since I think it is terrible, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably best suited for code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comparing hashed password, use [hash_equals](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php) instead.

```
if (hash_equals($hashed_password, crypt($user_input, $hashed_password))) {
   echo "Password verified!";
}
```

For your reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php